# How to use equal sign operators in an if and else statement

Tags: php

I have been trying to properly use equal operators to echo out some variables using if and else statements but my equal sign operator doesn't echo out accordingly.

```
<?php 
    $sql        = "SELECT * FROM customer_id_verification WHERE status='0'";
    $not_id_verify     = $database->query($sql);
    $id_verification   = $database->fetch_array($not_id_verify);
    $fetch_id          = $database->escape_value($id_verification['status']);

    $sql       = "SELECT * FROM customer_utility_verification WHERE status='0'";
    $not_util_verify        = $database->query($sql);
    $utility_verification   = $database->fetch_array($not_util_verify);
    $fetch_util             = $database->escape_value($utility_verification['status']);
?>
<?php 
    $sql        = "SELECT * FROM customer_id_verification WHERE status='1'";
    $id_verify         = $database->query($sql);
    $id_verification   = $database->fetch_array($id_verify);
    $fetch_ids          = $database->escape_value($id_verification['status']);

    $sql       = "SELECT * FROM customer_utility_verification WHERE status='1'";
    $util_verify            = $database->query($sql);
    $utility_verification   = $database->fetch_array($util_verify);
    $fetch_utils            = $database->escape_value($utility_verification['status']);

?>
```

I want each if and else statement to display one "li" statement at a time.

```
<?php 
      if($fetch_id == $fetch_util = 0){
    ?>  
    <li class="list-group-item"><a class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsidentification" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Verify Your account </a></li>
  <?php   
      }else{
    if($fetch_ids == $fetch_utils = 1){
        ?>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a class="btn bg-success" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Account Verified </a></li>
    <?php             
    }
  ?>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a class="btn btn-outline-warning" data-toggle="collapse" href="" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Verification Pending </a></li> 
 <?php 
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: Why do you have both == and = in your ifs?

Comment: @Shadow i was trying different things and that was the last i tried... try help out

Comment: No clue what you are trying to test in any of the ifs, but in general you need to use ==, not = in ifs. = is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fetch_id == $fetch_util = 0
```

Actually you are setting $fetch_util to 0.  '=' is an assignment operator.  This means that the value retrieved from the database
    $fetch_util = $database->escape_value($utility_verification['status']);
is overwritten by '0'

same with

```
$fetch_ids == $fetch_utils = 1
```

you are setting the value of $fetch_utils to '1'